# gitlab backup restore affects url redirection

Tags: postgresql, nginx, gitlab, redhat

I got a production server (ip:172.24.4.10) where GitLab 8.15.3 is installed.

Then I made a GitLab backup and I transferred the file to a test server(ip:172.24.4.50).
When I'm using a browser, I go to http://www.mygitlab.com which aims to ip 172.24.4.10.

The test server has same GitLab version and I executed the restore from backup file and it worked.

Even though, when I use the browser I go to http://172.24.4.50, it redirects to http://www.mygitlab.com.
It wasn't happening before restoration on test server.

I was checking gitlab, gitlab-nginx config files and I'm not finding something related to http://www.mygitlab.com.

What can I do?

P.D.
I put http://www.mygitlab.com as example.

Answer (score 1):

My PC was restarted becasuse there is a job in charged to restart PCs. After that, I used the browser going to http://172.24.4.50 and it started to work. So I think it was a cache browser issue and I didn't make any changes to gitlab config files.

Comment: OK, strange. I'll maintain my answer below, as I think it can add value for others who might not be in the exact same situation as you were.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't transfered/copied over your NGiNX settings, then it is a [GitLab configuration issue](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html).

Said configuration (for example in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`) does include:

```
external_url "http://gitlab.example.com"
```

Do check if the redirection comes from there.

Comment: Hi. I just restored the backup so I'm not sure if restoration has transfered/copied nginx settings. On gitlab.rb says external_url 'http://restore.com. Just it case, restore.com is host name but it doesn't say http://www.mygitlab.com

Comment: When I go to http://172.24.4.50. It says on gitlab-ctl tail as follows:
Started GET "/" for 172.24.9.15 at 2019-06-08 11:32:04 -0500
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Redirected to http://www.mygitlab.com/users/sign_in